# NumPy : How to transform the shape of an ndarray with a 'lossy' transformation

Tags: numpy, filtering

Consider an `ndarray` which contains 2 data points (`sample_rate_4[:,0]`, `sample_rate_4[:,1]`)  sampled at 4 times / second for 2 seconds. `sample_rate_4[0,:]` is the sample taken at 0 seconds, `sample_rate_4[1,:]` is the sample taken at 0.25 seconds
...
`sample_rate_4[8,:]` is the sample taken at 2 seconds

```
In [84]: sample_rate_4                                                                               
Out[84]: 
array([[12, 13],
       [14, 15],
       [ 6,  7],
       [16, 17],
       [10, 11],
       [ 2,  3],
       [ 4,  5],
       [ 8,  9],
       [ 0,  1]])
```

How can this data be transformed to the equivalent sampled at x times / seconds?. For example, if x = 3, I would expect the following result -

```
array([[12, 13],
       [14, 15],
       [16, 17],
       [10, 11],
       [ 2,  3],
       [ 8,  9],
       [ 0,  1]])
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem then your data contains 4 samples every second and you would like to remove the 4th sample every second, such that you are left with 3 samples every second.

This can be done as:

```
sample_rate_4 = array([[12, 13],
                       [14, 15],
                       [ 6,  7],
                       [16, 17], # this row will be removed
                       [10, 11],
                       [ 2,  3],
                       [ 4,  5],
                       [ 8,  9], # this row will be removed
                       [ 0,  1]])

out = np.delete(sample_rate_4, slice(3, None, 4), axis=0)

out
>>> array([[12, 13],
           [14, 15],
           [ 6,  7],
           [10, 11],
           [ 2,  3],
           [ 4,  5],
           [ 0,  1]])
```

`slice(3, None, 4)` is used to delete every 4th row starting at the 3rd row until the end (None).

Comment: I have discovered `numpy.interp` which close enough to my requirement, thanks anyway